# How do I make it so that people can use "https://" on my domain?

Tags: ssl, domain, http

When I put the 's" at the end of http for my domain name...this is what I see:

```
This Connection is Untrusted

You have asked Firefox to connect
securely to mydomain.com, but we can't confirm that your connection is secure.

Normally, when you try to connect securely,
sites will present trusted identification to prove that you are
going to the right place. However, this site's identity can't be verified.
```

How do I make it like everyone else?

Comment: Your certificate on the server is most probably self-signed.

Take a look at http://serverfault.com/questions/1453/setting-up-ssl-on-my-server for more info on what should be done.

Comment: I'm wondering do you actually *need* https, or do you just *want* it?  Maybe you should talk to your host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a SSL certificate on the server that hosts your web pages for that domain. If you don't control the server the hosting company might expect you to buy a cert. If you do control the server you can create your own certificate.

If it is for testing or personal use make your own certificate or ask your hosting provider to make one for you. If it is for business use pay to get one. There are different types but if you don't have one at all you probably want the cheapest one you can buy. Single domain or if you have multiple domains you might want a Multiple Domain (UCC) SSL. Multiple Domain UCC is cheaper than the Wildcard SSL most will suggest and suited my business needs just fine.

Answer (score 4):

You need to purchase a SSL certificate and install it on your web server.  How to do this depends on who is hosting your web site.

Comment: Typically your registrar will also sell these.  Verisign has good support, but is quite expensive for just a personal site.